# Additional click detected after upgrade to React 18. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

After updating to React 18, a simple 2 component Menu stopped working.  Menu is an icon you click on, and MenuBox opens when you click on Menu.

In React 17, I get the expected behavior as follows:

[image]

After upgrading to React 18, I get this behavior, which contains an extra click ...

[image]

Menu will only render MenuBox when it is clicked upon as seen here:

**Menu**

```
  function clicked() {
    console.log('DEBUG: Menu.jsx clicked')
    dispatch({type: 'toggleMenuPage'});
  }

  return (
    <div id="menu_hold">
      <SVGMenu onClick={clicked} id='menu_top'/>
      {menu && <MenuBox/>}
    </div>
  );
```

However after this click which toggles `menu` to true ...  `MenuBox` then detects a second click ( or propagating click have you ) which it should not do as it should not have even been rendered when the click on the Menu occurred.

**MenuBox**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('DEBUG: MenuBox.jsx useEffect()')
    function bodyClicked() {
      dispatch({type: 'toggleMenuPageOff'});
      console.log('DEBUG: MenuBox.jsx useEffect(): bodyClicked()')
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('click', bodyClicked);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', bodyClicked);
    };
  });
```

This "upgrade" breaks the menu as it is immediately closed upon opening so that you never see it.

I am not using strict mode.

I could not find anything relevant in the [changelog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74690351/additional-click-detected-after-upgrade-to-react-18-why?noredirect=1#comment131828047_74690351).

Comment: Usually this is due to `React.StrictMode`. What happens if you comment that out where you initially render?

Comment: It is not.  I am not using strict mode.

Comment: Try using strict mode and see if it displays any warnings

Comment: I could not find anything relevant in the [changelog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html)

Comment: I think I know what will fix your issue, but i am not sure what is causing it. I have had something similar happening after I upgraded to React 18.  Change your `clicked` method to `function clicked() {
    console.log('DEBUG: Menu.jsx clicked')
    dispatch({type: 'toggleMenuPage'});
  }`. Please let me know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is caused by React Strict mode. [Further explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNaPTkadnao)

Comment: It is not.  I am not using strict mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).